# Doing a Table Valued Function on Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am used to SQL Server so Oracle is new to me.  I have a need to do a table valued function in Oracle and I have pieced together the following code from different sites.  I need to pass in a parameter.  The first two create statements seem to run fine, no errors.  However, the Create function errors with:

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
> 'TBL_CREATININES'

Here is full code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tbl_lab_row AS OBJECT (
 EVENT_END_DT_TM DATE, 
 RESULT_VAL VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
 RESULT_UNITS_CD NUMBER, 
 EVENT_CD NUMBER
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tbl_creatinines AS TABLE OF tbl_lab_row;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tvf_creatinine_for_enc(p_enc_id NUMBER)
RETURN tbl_creatinines PIPELINED
IS
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (SELECT EVENT_END_DT_TM, RESULT_VAL, RESULT_UNITS_CD, EVENT_CD
            FROM SCHEMA.TABLE
            WHERE ENCNTR_ID = p_enc_id AND EVENT_CD IN(...listed codes here removed for brevity
    ))
  LOOP
    PIPE ROW (tbl_creatinines(r.EVENT_END_DT_TM, r.RESULT_VAL, r.RESULT_UNITS_CD, r.EVENT_CD));
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Cite your reference. What oracle documentation URL were you relying on for CREATE TYPE tbl_creatinines AS TABLE OF tbl_lab_row; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pipelined table function needs to pipe the *singular* object type, which will then be automatically converted into the *nested* table type. I modified the function below to work correctly, although I used `DUAL` and hard-coded values to avoid creating tables.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tvf_creatinine_for_enc(p_enc_id NUMBER)
RETURN tbl_creatinines PIPELINED
IS
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (SELECT sysdate EVENT_END_DT_TM, 'A' RESULT_VAL, 1 RESULT_UNITS_CD, 2 EVENT_CD
            FROM DUAL
            WHERE 1 = p_enc_id
    )
  LOOP
    PIPE ROW (tbl_lab_row(r.EVENT_END_DT_TM, r.RESULT_VAL, r.RESULT_UNITS_CD, r.EVENT_CD));
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
/

select * from table(tvf_creatinine_for_enc(1));
```

But not all table functions are pipelined. It's often easier, and probably faster, to build a function that simply returns a nested variable. The downside to this approach is that a large nested table variable may consume a lot of memory. Don't use this approach for returning a huge amount of data.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tvf_creatinine_for_enc2(p_enc_id NUMBER)
RETURN tbl_creatinines
IS
  v_rows tbl_creatinines;
BEGIN
  SELECT tbl_lab_row(EVENT_END_DT_TM => sysdate, RESULT_VAL => 'A', RESULT_UNITS_CD => 1 , EVENT_CD => 2)
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_rows  
  FROM DUAL
  WHERE 1 = p_enc_id;

  RETURN v_rows;
END;
/

select * from table(tvf_creatinine_for_enc2(1));
```

Comment: Jon, many thanks that was the issue.  For the second approach when you say a huge amount of data I assume you mean it would consume a decent percentage for the memory of the Oracle Server because it has to store the full table in memory before sending?

Comment: @Xaxum Yes, the entire result set must fit in server memory with the second approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to "push" the parameter deep into the SQL code where general predicate pushing by means of `where` condition have no access (sort of parameterized view), you may use SQL Macro (available since [19.7](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/newft/sql-macros-sqm.html)) as an alternative to a pipelined function.

The benefit is that SQL macro returns SQL code that is merged with other SQL code and you don't need to create new types. The drawback is that you cannot perform row-by-row processing inside (as long as it returns a part of SQL code), but some of them may be performed using available SQL constructs like recursive CTE, inline function declaration (`with function <funcname> ...`), `match_recognize`, `model`, lateral join etc.

```
create function f_get_dates(
  p_from date,
  p_to date,
  p_interval interval day to second default interval '1' day
)
return varchar2 sql_macro(table)
as
begin
  return q'{
  select
    trunc(f_get_dates.p_from) + (level - 1) * f_get_dates.p_interval as date_from
    , trunc(f_get_dates.p_from) + level * f_get_dates.p_interval as date_to
    , level as rn
  from dual
  connect by
    trunc(f_get_dates.p_from) + level * f_get_dates.p_interval <= trunc(f_get_dates.p_to)
  }';
end;/
```

```
select *
from f_get_dates(sysdate, sysdate + 4)
```

| DATE_FROM | DATE_TO | RN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-05 | 2023-05-06 | 1 |
| 2023-05-06 | 2023-05-07 | 2 |
| 2023-05-07 | 2023-05-08 | 3 |
| 2023-05-08 | 2023-05-09 | 4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_MyAIDc5)